# Is there such a thing as a chi-squared mixed model or mixed models for categorical data?

Tags: mixed-model, chi-squared-test

I conducted an intervention designed to help students acknowledge the validity of counterarguments in a debate. I did 2 separate debate exercises with them: one before, and one after the intervention. The class has native English speakers and ESL speakers.

Thus, I have **2 independent variables**: (1) time (before/after intervention) and (2) English ability (native, ESL)

My **dependent variable** here is whether students (1) integrated new perspectives in their final arguments (2) acknowledged other perspectives but ultimately retain original claim (3) dismissed new perspectives entirely (4) dismissed their original argument in favor of new perspectives.

Is there a way for me to check whether the DV has changed within (i.e., time) and between (i.e., English) groups, just like a mixed ANOVA?

Comment: Are you treating your outcome variable as ordered? If so searching for ordinal regression mixed effects model might bring up some useful leads.

Comment: @mdewey no, not really. Theoretically there are ways to order them, but at least 2 categories are on the same level.

Comment: The depend. variable (DV) is still not clear to me. Do you have 1 DV or 4 DVs? If there are 4 DVs, do you want to analyze them together as one 4-dimensional DV? Is each of the 4 DVs binary, ordinal, or numerical?

Comment: @amoeba There is only 1 DV (argumentation). Responses to the debate question were categorized into one of the 4 "levels" stated above.

Answer (score 2):

The pre-post design is a very weak design, and the results are easily manipulated because of time trends and lack of blinding.

A suitable model would be a mixed effects ordinal model such as the proportional odds ordinal logistic model.  Ideally you would do this with a Bayesian hierarchical model because frequentist methods here are not very accurate.  If you want a frequentist approach look at the R `ordinal` package.

Comment: Could you please explain why this could be a suitable model?

Comment: If you can assume the 4 levels are ordinal, such a model would make optimum use of the ordering while imposing no assumption about inter-category spacings.  The Bayesian part is to get exact inference without requiring the many frequentist approximations.